# Color.VALUE to text in JavaFX 8

Tags: colors, javafx-8

I'm trying to create a dropdown box/combo box for that contains multiple colors such as `Color.RED`, `Color.BLUE`, etc.. But when I run the program, it prints the colors in their hex form: 0xff0000. Actually, it prints them in some hex-like form that contains 8 numbers instead of 6: 0xff0000ff. I know it has something to do with the ObervableList. That's where I add the colors, and that's what the combo box gets the colors from. But how do I get it to just print "Red" or "Blue"?

```
Text diffuseColorText = new Text("Diffuse Color");
diffuseColorText.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 10));
ObservableList<Color> colorList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW,
    Color.GREEN, Color.PURPLE, Color.ORANGE);
ComboBox<Color> dColors = new ComboBox<>(colorList);
dColors.setPromptText("Color of Box");
dColors.setPrefSize(150, 30);
dColors.setOnAction(event -> {
    diffuseColor = ((ComboBox<Color>) event.getSource()).getValue();
    mymaterial.setDiffuseColor(diffuseColor);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Color.toString` prints the channels (including alpha) and there's nothing you can do about it.

You could use a `Map<String, Color>` though to map from strings to color:

```
Map<String, Color> colors = new LinkedHashMap<>();
colors.put("RED", Color.RED);
...
colors.put("ORANGE", Color.ORANGE);

ObservableList<String> colorList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(colors.keySet());
ComboBox<String> dColors = new ComboBox<>(colorList);
dColors.setPromptText("Color of Box");
dColors.setPrefSize(150, 30);
dColors.setOnAction(event -> {
    diffuseColor = colors.get(((ComboBox<String>) event.getSource()).getValue());
    mymaterial.setDiffuseColor(diffuseColor);
});
```

If reflection is available and you want to list **all** colors available via fields in the `Color` class, you could also use it to the `Color`s:

```
private static final int PUBLIC_STATIC = Modifier.PUBLIC | Modifier.STATIC;

...

Map<String, Color> colors = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (Field field : Color.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    if (field.getType() == Color.class && (field.getModifiers() & PUBLIC_STATIC) == PUBLIC_STATIC ) {
        colors.put(field.getName(), (Color) field.get(null));
    }
}
```